# API for finding Administrative Divisions

Tags: maps, semantic-web, wikipedia, dbpedia

Is there any endpoint or API to query Wikipedia, DBpedia or something similar to get all the Wikipedia pages of all the countries and its respective administrative divisions?

I've tried to find in DBpedia the way to know the administrative sub-divisions of a given region but I couldn't do it.

Comment: Just a shot in the dark here, but if you don't have anywhere to start yet, I would query `https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=xxx&titles=yyy|zzz`, with `xxx` being the format (`json`, `yaml`, etc) and `yyy`/`zzz` being the pages to query (eg. `Germany|Scotland`). Also, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_country_subdivisions_by_area might help.

Comment: Thank you, I'll take a look at it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would instead query against Wikidata and then convert the reults to Wikipedia pages.

You can use [Sweden](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q34) as an example for how a country and its subdivisions are structured.

For the querying you can use either
https://query.wikidata.org (SPARQL) or
http://wdq.wmflabs.org

Answer (score 1):

You can try looking at [Despegar](http://dev.despegar.com). You can retrieve Administrative Divisions using this RESTful APIs. Here's [link](https://api.despegar.com/v3/docs/method/geo-all-administrative-divisions) to method you need.

Comment: You have to pay for it isn't it?